# Ruby CSV re-arranging Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv

I'm not sure what the appropriate title for this question so if someone could help me with that also, it would be nice.

-
I have a CSV file that looks something like

```
ID | Num
a  | 1
a  | 2
a  | 3
b  | 4
b  | 5
c  | 6
c  | 7
```

I need the result to be:

```
ID | Num
a  | 1,2,3,4
b  | 4,5
c  | 6,7
```

Currently, my solution is:

```
ary = CSV.open('some_file')

final = Array.new
id = ary[1][0] # ary[0] is "id"
numJoin = ary[1][1]

(1..ary.length).each do |i|
  if id == ary[i+1][0]
    numJoin = numJoin + "," + ary[i+1][1]
  else
    final << [id,numJoin]
    id = ary[i+1][0]
    numJoin = ary[i+1]]1]
  end
end
```

It works, but I would like to have the opportunity to learn other ways to solve this, as I think there should be simpler ways to do this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain the logic. It is not clear.

Comment: Your result contains `4` twice, is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by`, which groups by the *return* value of the block passed to it, in this case, it's the ID.

```
ary = ary.group_by { |v| v[0] }
```

P.S That file ain't looking like a CSV.